# Isometry group of regular octagon, find commutating elements and 2 specific subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In isometry group of regular octagon

$D_{16} = < g,s | \ g^8=1=s^2, sgs=g^{-1}>$

a) Describe a set of elements commutating with all elements of the group.

b) Find 2 subgroups

$A,B \subset D_{16}$ that $A \lhd B, B \lhd D_{16}$, but $A \not\unlhd D_{16}$

What's the way to solve problem like this?

Comment: Part (a) is an abstract duplicate of this question: [Determine the center of the dihedral group of order 12](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252960/determine-the-center-of-the-dihedral-group-of-order-12)

Comment: (Also, do you mean $A$ is *not* normal in $D_{16}$, rather than is normal?)

Comment: I mean exactly A is normal in B, B is normal in $D_{16}$, but A is not normal in $D_{16}$

Comment: okay, I've edited your post to say this.

Comment: Thanks very much. I couldnt find that sign.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an a) part.

If there is $g^k s \in Z(G)$ so

$g g^k s = g^k s  g$

$g^{k+1} s = g^{k-1}$

$gsg =  g^{k-1}s $

$g^2 = 1$, contradiction

Let's

$g^k \in Z(G)$

$sgs = g^{-1}$, sp $sg^ks = g^{-k}$

but $sg^ks = ssg^k = g^k$

then  $g^k = g^{-k}$

at last $k = 0$ or $k = 4$

answer: $Z(D_{16}) = \{ 1, g^4\}$